# Biztalk 2013 WCF-webhttp (WCF web publishing wizard) not exposing schemas

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

Wonder if you guys can help. I have used the BizTalk WCF Service Publishing wizard to expose an Orchestration via WCF-WebHttp, and I can see the service and I am able to send requests to it via SOAPUi etc, however, I cannot see any of the schemas when I try and add the service reference to a .NET application. I've ensured that the schemas are in the same project, and that the actual DLL is GAC'd before deploying the service.

I've looked at the wsdl but I cannot see anything related to the schemas.

```
<wsdl:types>
   <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message">
      <xs:complexType name="MessageBody">
         <xs:sequence>
             <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="##any" /> 
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="ITwoWayAsync_BizTalkSubmit_InputMessage">
   <wsdl:part name="message" type="q1:MessageBody" xmlns:q1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="ITwoWayAsync_BizTalkSubmit_OutputMessage">
     <wsdl:part name="BizTalkSubmitResult" type="q2:MessageBody" xmlns:q2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="ITwoWayAsync">
  <wsdl:operation name="BizTalkSubmit">
  <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="BizTalkSubmit" message="tns:ITwoWayAsync_BizTalkSubmit_InputMessage" /> 
  <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/2006/r2/wcf-adapter/ITwoWayAsync/BizTalkSubmitResponse" message="tns:ITwoWayAsync_BizTalkSubmit_OutputMessage" /> 
 </wsdl:operation>
 </wsdl:portType>
 <wsdl:service name="BizTalkServiceInstance" /> 
</wsdl:definitions>
```

When I try and add a service reference to the service, it successfully adds the reference, but for the method called BizTalkSubmit, it only takes a parameter of System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Regards

Jazzyuk

Comment: WCF-WebHttp doesn't use WSDLs or "strongly typed" messaging.  You're mixing paradigms here in a way that doesn't necessarily make sense.  If you want to use strongly typed messaging and have the functionality to add a service reference, use a SOAP based protocol like WCF-WSHttp/BasicHttp

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you publish using WCF-WSHttp first, then changing to WCF-WebHttp afterwards. This will enable you to choose a schema to publish:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, so just to confirm, publish the schemas first, then change the transport in the receive port in BizTalk Admin to WCF-WebHttp? Thanks

Comment: Yes, the publishing wizard is simply a means to an end, to generate the service's WSDL. You will then be able to add the service reference on the client, and have the proxy classes generated for you.

Comment: Just keep in mind that if you use WCF-WebHttp, you're designing a restful service..  WSDL doesn't really fit into that context anymore.  @Gruff, are you sure this method will really work once it's changed to WCF-WebHttp?  If it does, it won't be as reliable as if you were really exposing a SOAP based interface.

Comment: @DanField. I'd thought that originally too, however, I'd thought that if I'm exposing a service to a customer, how would they be able to validate the response? If they have an object (similar to how it would be if you had connected to a non-rest service, with schemas being retrievable, then that would work (happy to be corrected on the above, just thinking out aloud..))

Comment: Yes, but then why use REST at all?  If you're sending and receivign **objects**, use the **Simple Object Access Protocol** :)

Comment: Hmmm, admittedly, I haven't tested it with WCF-WebHttp. I agree with @DanField, it doesn't seem like you should bother with WCF-WebHttp :)

Comment: OK guys. Thanks very much for your input. I'll probably go down the route of exposing the endpoint as a WCF-WebHttp (to cater for our REST service plan going forward) and just send out the schemas for the responses and requests in a separate document.